# How do you rectangulate a quadilateral selection in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

What this is for is that, i have a lot of scanned documents with passport size photos in each of them. The photos are aligned randomly. I need to separate them out.
What i currently do is make selection using `polygonal marquee` tool, then use `Free Transform` to straighten it out and later crop, resize and save the pp photo.
I want to define an action that would automatically turn my selection into a properly aligned rectangle and crop the selection.
Is there a way to achieve this in a way better than my current way?

Comment: How would the action know the direction and extent of the Free Transform you are performing? I assume each selection is different.

Comment: I would give it the 4 corners of a randomly aligned quadilateral and somehow the action should be able to transform the 4 corners into a regular predefined and properly aligned rectangle. Would this even be possible?
Yes, every selection is different.

Comment: Nope. Not possible in actions. *Might* be possible in a script.

Comment: I *love* the wording of this question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Photoshop CS6 or newer, the [Perspective Crop tool](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/perspective-crop-tool-cs6/) might be just what you're looking for. Hit C to select the Crop tool, then Shift-C for Perspective Crop.

There's two ways you can use this: Click the four corners of the item as you've been doing with Polygonal Marquee, or drag a rough rectangle around the item and then adjust the corners individually into the quadrilateral shape you desire. Then just hit Enter and Photoshop will re-perspectivize the quadrilateral into a perfect rectangle.

Comment: I have CS5. But I was thinking of upgrading anyway, so now seems to be the best time.
I just did some research on perspective crop and it seems to be exactly what i want. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to click the green "Accept answer" checkmark button if my answer was the one you needed. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop has a built-in script that is designed for exactly this purpose. It goes back at least to Photoshop 6, iirc.

From the File menu, choose `Automate > Crop and Straighten Photos` (that's a clue, right there) and let the program work its magic.

This works for single or multiple images within a single image, and creates new documents for each extracted image.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work for me. The selection is not mapped correctly into the cropped image.